# How do I solve this Sprite Kit (Swift3) Error?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

```
import SpriteKit
extension GameScene {

    func addPlayer() {
        player = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red , size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
```

This shows error saying

> Cannot assign value of type 'SKSpriteNode' to type 'SKSpriteNode!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<SKSpriteNode>.Type')

[image]

Comment: Update your question showing how `player` is declared.

Comment: How did you define player?

Comment: He probably done something like `var player:SKSpriteNode.Type!`

Answer (score 0):

Define your player like this:

```
var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "YourImageForTheNode")
// or just...
var player = SKSpriteNode()
```